# Activating virtualenv through sshfs(fuse)

Tags: python, python-3.x, fuse, sshfs

I have 5 Linux_x86_64 PCs that I’d like to setup a mini cluster with. Each of these machines mount a remote directory by using sshfs(fuse) and remote machine is also Linux_x86_64.

`sshfs username@somemachine:/home/username/ ~/somemachine/`

I should mention that I have read/write/exec permissions on this directory at local. There is a virtualenv located under home directory on the remote machine, python version is 3.5. As I was trying to activate this virtualenv on local by executing `source ~/somemachine/venv/bin/activate`, I got an error due to a hardcoded path inside the activate script. I got around it but problems still continue when I run python.

```
Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
Could not find platform dependent libraries <exec_prefix>
Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]
```

I believe there is a problem with $PYTHONHOME or `sys.path` which is closely related to python installation process. Python cannot seem to find built-in modules to start. How can I get around this situation? Also, I want to emphasize that this might not be the best approach to using virtual environments but this is my setup and it would be great to get it to work.